# mqjbnd05 error when deploying app on websphere

Tags: websphere, message-queue, ibm-mq

I have a fresh install of Wesphere 6.1 Fixpack 23. I have an app deployed that requires an MQSeries JMS Queue. I set up an MQSeries provider-based request and reply queue and an MQSeries provider-based queue connection factory. When the deployed app tries to access the queue, I receive the following error.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

[5/28/09 10:33:42:538 EDT] 00000033 ServletWrappe E   SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the servlet: espaapp. Exception thrown : org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested **exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: *mqjbnd05 (Not found in java.library.path)*
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: mqjbnd05 (Not found in java.library.path)**
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:953)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:922)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:451)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.loadLib(MQSESSION.java:1028)
    at com.ibm.mq.server.MQSESSION$1.run(MQSESSION.java:246)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:192)
    at com.ibm.mq.server.MQSESSION.(MQSESSION.java:243)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:177)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSIONServer.getMQSESSION(MQSESSIONServer.java:68)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.getSession(MQSESSION.java:508)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:213)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQBindingsManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQBindingsManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:186)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQBindingsManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQBindingsManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:225)
    at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.(StoredManagedConnection.java:84)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:173)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:795)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:709)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:664)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:160)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.(MQQueueManager.java:550)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSPIQueueManager.(MQSPIQueueManager.java:62)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.createQM(MQConnection.java:2427)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.createQMXA(MQConnection.java:1806)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection.(MQQueueConnection.java:105)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection.(MQQueueConnection.java:66)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAQueueConnection.(MQXAQueueConnection.java:59)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAQueueConnectionFactory.createXAQueueConnection(MQXAQueueConnectionFactory.java:82)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedQueueConnection.createConnection(JMSManagedQueueConnection.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedConnection.(JMSManagedConnection.java:315)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedQueueConnection.(JMSManagedQueueConnection.java:71)
... More

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?
[java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError occurs when connecting to a queue manager](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21248900)

Also, within the JMS -> Queue Connection Factories section, select your Queue Connection Factory and check if your "Transport Type" is set to 'BINDINGS' or 'CLIENT'

I swapped mine to CLIENT and that seemed to help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Such error often happens as a result of passing `null` to `port`, `host` or `QManager` to connection factory. Try to check all parameters during execution. Normally MQ does not require mqjbnd05 library.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find this file

```
libmqjbnd05.so
```

Add that to the LIBPATH for your JVM and try again.

Answer (score 0):

GO to WebSphere Admin console. Environment ->  WebSphere variables. Look for MQ_INSTALL_ROOT and modify its value to your MQ installation directory [MQ Home].