# Put message into queue from Java

Tags: java, mq

I am trying to put a message into queue from my Java code(in my local machine). I am getting the error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mqjbnd05 in java.library.path.

This is my code :

```
qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager);
int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT ;

MQQueue queue = qMgr.accessQueue("Q1",openOptions); 
MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
msg.writeUTF("this is a test message"); 

MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
queue.put(msg, pmo); 

MQMessage retrievedMessage = new MQMessage();
retrievedMessage.messageId = msg.messageId;

MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
queue.get(retrievedMessage, gmo);
String msgText = retrievedMessage.readUTF();
System.out.println("The message is: " + msgText);

queue.close();
qMgr.disconnect();
```

My Queue Manager is `QM_FORD` and queue name is Q1. Listener port is 1414.
The environment variables are set properly. 
Can anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mqjbnd05 error when deploying app on websphere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921199/mqjbnd05-error-when-deploying-app-on-websphere)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your Java code. Unsatisfied Link Error means a native library (.dll in Windows, .so in Unix) is not being found. It's either missing, or not referenced in an environment variable: PATH (Windows) or LD_LIBRARY_PATH or LIBPATH, etc, depending on what operating system this is in.

[googling may give you a few ideas](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS389US389&aq=0&oq=java.lang.Unsatisfied&sugexp=chrome,mod=8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the missing LIBRARY PATH. Set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to "MQ_INSTALLATION_DIR"/java/lib (For Unix)